# New Automation Data format in Logic Pro 10.5

Tags: daw, logic-pro

After updating the Logic Pro to 10.5, I opened an old project of mine and this popped up...

[image]

```
What is this "new format"?
```

and

```
How is it different from the older one?
```

---

P.S : The project opened and worked just fine. Aside from the visual differences, I couldn't find any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been some **major changes in automation** in Logic Pro 10.5.

[image]

Apple will not divulge any internal changes/optimisation they've made but this major a change can be attributed to the "new format" and hence answers the reason behind the warning.

Source : [Logic Pro X 10.5 release notes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203718)